# Why does an op amp have two offset pins?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

This is the pinout of a simple op amp. Why does it have two offset pins?

An offset is used to apply a DC offset to the output voltage, right?

Then why are there two?

Comment: Have you looked at the rest of the datasheet? The clue is they are "offset NULL" for getting rid of the offset, not to provide an offset.

Comment: But to get rid of the offset, you have to apply an offset (of opposite polarity). If there was only one pin it would require a complicated circuit to introduce a positive or a negative offset (offset can be pos or neg so you need both options). With 2 pins that is easier, see Andy's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this explain it: -

[image]

Note there are two pins on the op-amp for connecting to a potentiometer.

Comment: Really thanks, I was totally misunderstanding the whole concept!